# Java Game Image Buffering Leaves Tail

Tags: java, graphics, buffer, bufferstrategy

I have the following class (Snippet), and in my `render()` method, I am doing buffering using `BufferStrategy`. The issue I am having is when I move an image, it leaves a tail.

[image: Example with tail]

What Do I need to do with my code to make it so the tail doesn't show? Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;

    public synchronized void start(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        // Main Game Loop
        this.render();
        // End Main Game Loop
    }

    protected void render(){
        if(bufferStrategy == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            bufferStrategy = this.getBufferStrategy();
        }
        Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
        // Loop through a list of items to draw
        for(GameObject go : gameObjects){
            Image sprite = go.getComponent(SpriteRenderer.class).getSprite();
            Vector2 pos = go.getComponent(Transform.class).getPosition();
            g.drawImage(sprite, (int)pos.x, (int)pos.y, this);
        }
        g.dispose();
        bufferStrategy.show();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I figured it out:

```
Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
super.paint(g);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh every time the wheel moves and repaint the Canvas to black before painting the wheel's position again.